# Off diagonal elements of $A^TCA$

Tags: matrices

Let's consider $$D=A^TCA$$

where $C$ is a positive-definite and diagonal matrix. However, A is not necessarily square.

What is the necessary and satisfactory condition for $A$ to have each of the? following

- $D$ is diagonal.
- $D$ is not diagonal.

Comment: @JazzyMatrix, Great point. But is C still commutative even if A is non-square?

Comment: @WillJagy, Yes all elements are real. Unfortunately A is not a column vector.

Comment: @WillJagy, I am considering such a [QP problem](https://au.mathworks.com/help/mpc/examples/solve-custom-mpc-quadratic-programming-problem-and-generate-code.html) where it says `H = CONV'*Q_hat*CONV + R_hat;`

Comment: @WillJagy, I have done a especial case where $A$ is square (which is normally not) and reached to $a_{11}c_{11}a_{12}+a_{21}c_{22}a_{22}=0$. I dont know what to conclude.

Comment: My purpose is to find out how two optimization variables will depend on each other (Off-diagonal elements).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ is an $n \times m$ matrix.

Since $C$ is positive-definite and diagonal, let $R$ be the root of $C$ (so a real $n \times n$ diagonal matrix such as $R^2 = C$). Then $D = {^{t}(RA)}(RA)$.

Let $B = RA$ then $C$ is diagonal if and only if the column vectors of $B$ are orthogonal, i.e. if $B = (B_{1},..., B_{m})$ where $B_{i} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ then

$$\forall i \neq j \, \, \, {^{t}B_{i}}B_{j} = 0$$

This mean in particular that if $m > n$ then $A$ necessarily has $m-n$ null columns.

Comment: Thanks very much. Normally, $m>n$ as the number of states in many systems in more than the number of inputs.

Comment: It seems there is a typo as the transpose sign is before $B_i$.